# Use text box to go to a specific page

Tags: html, text, field

For my website, I want to create a text field to go to a specific page. I've done some research but I couldn't find the right answer.

So the thing is;

If someone types '2000' in the textbox, it has to open a new window with the URL www.exampledomain.com/2000. When someone types '1384' it has to open www.exampledomain.com/1384. I don't get it to work. It has to work with a search button and an enter. I think its a basic question, and I'm a beginner, so I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review our guide for asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This question definitely needs some clarification, because there are literally DOZENS of ways to accomplish this. We need more information, like what languages you can and cannot use, and what languages you have already written code in.

Comment: Please post any code you have tried so far.

Comment: you should put code samples for us to easily reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
function goToPage(e) {
  let url="http://www.exampledomain.com/"+e.target.value;  
  console.log(url);
  window.location = url;
}
```

```html
Type page number and press enter
<input onchange="goToPage(event)">
```